# How can I extract data from all elements of a multiset?

Tags: function, functional-programming, isabelle, algebraic-data-types, multiset

Let's say I have a datatype called `dtyp`. It looks like this

`datatype dtype = T bool int`

I'd like to define a function `extr :: "dtype multiset => int multiset"` which takes a multiset of these `dtype` elements and returns a multiset containing the ints in each of the `dtype` elements. So for example:

`value "extr {#T True 4, T False 5, T False 7#}"` should give `{#4,5,7#}`

I first thought of iterating through the multiset, but I know it isn't possible as these multisets are based off normal sets which are not iterable. I then thought about universal quantifiers, but I'm not sure how to use them in this situation. Could I please have some help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some fancy syntax to define the extractor directly:

```
datatype dtype = T bool (payload: int)
```

Thinking about sets is a good starting point: you are looking for `image` for multisets. That function exists and it is called `image_mset`. So:

```
definition extr :: "dtype multiset => int multiset" where
  "extr = image_mset payload"
```

The syntax `# for image_mset has not yet been added to the Multiset entry, but it is used by various people.

```
notation image_mset (infixr "`#" 90)
```

Comment: Addendum: you can also do `λx. case x of T _ y ⇒ y`, or define `payload` using pattern matching with the `fun` or `primrec` command.